# Difference between range operator and Span

Tags: c#, range, slice

consider this program

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            Span<byte> span = array;
            byte[] dest = new byte[4];
            //span.CopyTo(dest);  // ok
            span.CopyTo(dest[..]);  // NO
            //span.CopyTo(dest.AsSpan());  // ok
            //span.CopyTo(dest.AsSpan()[..]);  // ok

            Console.Out.Write(BitConverter.ToString(dest));
        }
    }
}
```

On the // NO line I expected

> 01-02-03-04

but got

> 00-00-00-00

What's happening?

Comment: what has this question to di with HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dest[..]` creates a new array. So it's a bit like this code:

```cs
byte[] dest = new byte[4];

// This is what the range operator is doing
byte[] actualDest = new byte[4];
dest.CopyTo(actualDest);

// dest and actualDest are separate arrays now,
// so this doesn't affect the content of dest at all
span.CopyTo(actualDest);
```

A simpler (IMO) example without using spans at all:

```cs
int[] original = new int[1];
int[] range = original[..];

// Prints False, because the variables
// refer to separate arrays
Console.WriteLine(range == original);

range[0] = 10;

// Prints 0 as the two arrays are separate.
Console.WriteLine(original[0]);
```

Comment: Alright I'm lessoned. But it's surprising behavior. I wouldn't expect a slicing syntax to cause expensive duplicates, it feels natural that it would generate a span (=a view).

Comment: @v.oddou: And if you want that behaviour, you can get it by using `AsSpan`. But arrays themselves don't have the notion of a view... there's no such thing as a `byte[]` which is a view over a different `byte[]`. (That's why historically we've had `ArraySegment`.)